# How to i access a dictionary with several lists

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary

So i have a total dictionary which is set to empty, and i appended a url & duration to it, now there are multiple urls and durations in the dictionary, the durations are all stored in a list, i'm trying to access each individual list to add the numbers in them together, but i cant access it, anyone knows how to ?

```py
    import time
    import unittest
    import json
    from selenium import webdriver


    class Tester(unittest.TestCase):
        "doc string"
        def setUp(self):
            "doc string"
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("/Users/tamerjar/Desktop/chromedriver")
            self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            self.verificationErrors = []


    def test_er(self):
        "doc string"
        driver = self.driver

        # This is the total dictionary where im trying to access the ['duration']
        total = {}

        print("total" + str(total))
        durations = []
        with open('output.txt', 'w') as json_file:
            for result in range(10):
                driver.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_metric")
                result = driver.execute_script('return window.performance.getEntries()')
                print(result)


                for current in result:
                    #This is where i appended to the total
                    url = current['name']
                    current_list = total.get(url, [])
                    current_list.append(current['duration'])
                    total[url] = current_list


                    print("current list" + str(current_list))
                    print("total" + str(total))
                    print(current['name'])
                    print(current['duration'])
                    print(current.keys())
                    json_file.write(f"{current['name']}, {current['duration']}\n")
                    print("Total final : " + str(total))





        # with open('mycsv.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        #     for key in total.keys():
        #     csv_file.write(f'{key}, {average}')

        with open('json_output' + '.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(result, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)



    def tearDown(self):
        self.driver.quit()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand it right. Maybe you can show an example of the mentioned dictionary.
***If*** I understood right you are just trying to iterate over the key/value pairs (`key` being the url and `value` being your list with the durations?) of the dictionary? That you can do like this:

```
for key, value in your_dict.items():
    print(key, value)
    # using the sum function
    sum1 = sum(value)
    # or calculate on your own by iterating the list
    sum2 = 0
    for i in value:
        sm2 += i
    # result is the same
    print(sum1, sum2)
```

If you want to sum all durations over all the items you can do it just the same way. You just need to assign a sum variable outside of the iteration loops and add to that.

Comment: Thanks for your response, yes that works, but for my value pair which is a list of numbers, I'm trying to add them together in the loop, any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, I think you have saved some of the data in a dictionary total whose keys are different urls. And you are trying to access the values of the dictionary. Is it right?

If yes I think you can do the following to traverse through the list and manipulate the values of the dictionary.

```python
for x in total:
     list = total[x]
#here x will be the url and list will provide with the data you have saved with the url.
```

Let me know if I made a mistake in comprehension.

Comment: Thanks for your response too!, this gave me all the lists number which i wanted, i also was finding a way to add these number in the list and display each of their added version, if that made sense. I'm sorry for the unstructured question!

Comment: Yeah I think @roxtii has shown it correctly in his answer. To display the sum of the numbers in a list you can just do `print (sum(list))`